# react-bootstrap weird gradient on my component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Why am I having a weird css theme?
I'm navigating the react-bootstrap docs here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/ and did exactly what's on the doc but somehow my implementation has this weird gradient going on instead of a flat color. This happens for all of my components also (buttons etc.)

My output:
[image: My implementation]

The site's output:
[image: The output in the docs]

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the docs, you notice that they tell you to put two stylesheets (probably into your index.html in your React app):

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Just remove the optional theme line, and the gradient will go away.